# Verify if a certain image exists

Tags: c#, leanft

I am trying to check if a certain image (the output of a a test result) exists in a browser session.

I am using the C# SDK.

Following an example of code from Micro Focus, the verification procedure uses a line of code like one that follows the remarks:

```
Point?: point = browser.VerifyImageExists(imageToFind);
```

The issue I have is: how can I check the contents of the variable point, and which data type it has?

I am using the UFT LeanFT version 14.03.

Comment: Why do you have a colon (`:`) after the "`Point?`" are you sure that belongs there?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/NetSDKReference/webframe.html#HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.ITestObject~VerifyImageExists.html):

```
Nullable<Point> VerifyImageExists( 
   Image imageToFind,
   byte similarity
)
```

> **Return Value**
>   the Point where the image was located, or `null` if it was not found.

So the return value is a [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Nullable%601)&rd=true) of type [`System.Drawing.Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx).

**Usage:**

```
Point? point = browser.VerifyImageExists(imageToFind);
if (point.HasValue) {
    Console.WriteLine("Image found at {0}", point.Value);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Image not found");
}
```

Comment: @Adelin, I linked to which point, but you're right, it'll be better to explicitly say so in the answer.

Comment: The code runs Motti but the result is always not found; I'm just doing a proof of concept searching an image on a Google page; My starting point was a JPEG google searched image (I had to transform it on bmp for LeanFT to use it)

Comment: @JoseMCardoso Try adding a similarity, perhaps the conversion from JPEG to BMG changed it a bit.

Comment: I guess it did< I lowered Granularity just to 45 and it didn't work. Anyhow I will try to reuse the code later in another proof of concept with no image manipulation,

Comment: Don't know why it didn't work. I tried a different approach and issue got solved. Used the Insight functions and achieved to determine where an image was, the image format could be a *.png